# How to show the yAxisRight of value in markerview for mpandroidchart line chart?

Tags: android, marker, linechart, mpandroidchart

I use `mpandroidchart` for my project and it's a line chart.

I don't know how to show the `yAxisRight` value in my markerview. My custom markerview has three `TextView`s and they are put vertical. The first shows xAxis value , the second shows the left yAxis value , and I want show the `yAxisRight` value in the third `TextView`, but I don't know how to do that.

The following is my code:

```
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
      if (fundType.equals("2") && wssFlag == 3) 
      {
        // the xAxis value: 
        mDate.setText(date+" "+xVal.get(e.getXIndex())); 
        mNetValue.setText("估值：");
        // the left yAxis value: 
        mJingZhiData.setText(formatNumber(e.getVal(), 4, true,'.')); 
      }
}
```

![my screenshot]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R32eI.png